# Getting Link From Adapter To Activity And Then Opening Link In External Player?

Tags: java, android

I have a video streaming app which works fine with ExoPlayer2 but my users now want me to add an option to play video in External Player so I'm trying to write an intent but can't seem to.

My adapter from where the link has to be taken:

```
public class ServerApater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder> {

    private List<CommonModels> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context ctx;

    private ServerApater.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    private ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder viewHolder;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj, int position, OriginalViewHolder holder);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ServerApater.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public ServerApater(Context context, List<CommonModels> items) {
        this.items = items;
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_server, parent, false);
        vh = new ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        CommonModels obj = items.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(obj.getTitle());

        if (position==0){
            viewHolder=holder;
            new DetailsActivity().iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),ctx);
            holder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, items.get(position), position,holder);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name;
        public CardView cardView;

        public OriginalViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            cardView=v.findViewById(R.id.card_view_home);
        }
    }

    public void chanColor(ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder,int pos){

        if (pos!=0){
            viewHolder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_60));
        }

        if (holder!=null){
            holder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_60));
        }



    }

}
```

Now the issue is, I don't know how to. "obj.getStremURL()" in my intent says "Cannot resolve symbol 'obj'"

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

My activity:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i = 0;

    private TextView tvName,tvDirector,tvRelease,tvCast,tvDes,tvGenre,tvRelated;


    private RecyclerView rvDirector,rvServer,rvRelated,rvComment;

    public static RelativeLayout lPlay;

    private EpisodeAdapter episodeAdapter;
    private HomePageAdapter relatedAdapter;
    private LiveTvHomeAdapter relatedTvAdapter;

    public static LinearLayout llBottom,llBottomParent,llcomment;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private String type="",id="";

    private ImageView imgAddFav;

    public static ImageView imgBack;
    public static ImageView imgPlayer;

    private String V_URL = "";
    public static WebView webView;
    public static ProgressBar progressBar;
    private boolean isFav = false;

    private ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;

    private Button btnComment;
    private EditText etComment;
    private CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter;

    private String commentURl;
    private AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public static SimpleExoPlayer player;
    public static PlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    public static SubtitleView subtitleView;

    public static ImageView imgFull;
    public static ImageView imgfit;

    public static boolean isPlaying,isFullScr;
    public static View playerLayout;

    private int playerHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        imgPlayer=findViewById(R.id.img_player);

        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();

        playerHeight = lPlay.getLayoutParams().height;

        progressBar.setMax(100); // 100 maximum value for the progress value
        progressBar.setProgress(50);

        imgBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        imgPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(obj.getStremURL()), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));

            }
});

        type = getIntent().getStringExtra("vType");
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        final SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (preferences.getBoolean("status",false)){
            imgAddFav.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }else {
            imgAddFav.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        imgFull.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isFullScr){
                    isFullScr=false;
                    showSystemUI();
                    llBottomParent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    lPlay.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, playerHeight));
                    imgfit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    hideSystemUI();
                    isFullScr=true;
                    llBottomParent.setVisibility(GONE);
                    lPlay.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    imgfit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            i++;
                            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    i = 0;
                                }
                            };

                            if (i == 1) {
                                //Single click
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
                            } else if (i == 2) {
                                //Double click
                                i = 0;
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
                            } else if (i == 3) {
                                // Triple Click
                                i = 0;
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
                            }  else if (i == 4) {
                                // Fourth Click
                                i = 0;
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }


            }
        });

        imgAddFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String url = new ApiResources().getAddFav()+"&&user_id="+preferences.getString("id","0")+"&&videos_id="+id;

                if (isFav){
                    String removeURL = new ApiResources().getRemoveFav()+"&&user_id="+preferences.getString("id","0")+"&&videos_id="+id;
                    removeFromFav(removeURL);
                }else {
                    addToFav(url);
                }
            }
        });


        if (!isNetworkAvailable()){
            new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError(getString(R.string.no_internet));
        }

        initGetData();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                initGetData();
            }
        });
    }


    private void initGetData(){

        if (!type.equals("tv")){

            //----related rv----------
            relatedAdapter=new HomePageAdapter(this,listRelated);
            rvRelated.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            rvRelated.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvRelated.setAdapter(relatedAdapter);

            if (type.equals("tvseries")){

                rvRelated.removeAllViews();
                listRelated.clear();
                rvServer.removeAllViews();
                listDirector.clear();
                listEpisode.clear();

                episodeAdapter=new EpisodeAdapter(this,listDirector);
                rvServer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                rvServer.setHasFixedSize(true);
                rvServer.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
                getSeriesData(type,id);
            }else {
                rvServer.removeAllViews();
                listDirector.clear();
                rvRelated.removeAllViews();
                listRelated.clear();

                serverApater=new ServerApater(this,listDirector);
                rvServer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
                rvServer.setHasFixedSize(true);
                rvServer.setAdapter(serverApater);
                getData(type,id);

                final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder[] viewHolder = {null};
                serverApater.setOnItemClickListener(new ServerApater.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj, int position, ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder) {
                        iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),DetailsActivity.this);

                        serverApater.chanColor(viewHolder[0],position);
                        holder.name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        viewHolder[0] =holder;
                    }
                });
            }

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
            String url = new ApiResources().getFavStatusURl()+"&&user_id="+sharedPreferences.getString("id","0")+"&&videos_id="+id;

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("status",false)){
                getFavStatus(url);
            }

        }else {

            llcomment.setVisibility(GONE);

            tvRelated.setText("All TV :");

            rvServer.removeAllViews();
            listDirector.clear();
            rvRelated.removeAllViews();
            listRelated.clear();

            //----related rv----------
            relatedTvAdapter=new LiveTvHomeAdapter(this,listRelated);
            rvRelated.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            rvRelated.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvRelated.setAdapter(relatedTvAdapter);

            imgAddFav.setVisibility(GONE);

            serverApater=new ServerApater(this,listDirector);
            rvServer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            rvServer.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvServer.setAdapter(serverApater);
            getTvData(type,id);
            llBottom.setVisibility(GONE);

            final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder[] viewHolder = {null};
            serverApater.setOnItemClickListener(new ServerApater.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj, int position, ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder) {
                    iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),DetailsActivity.this);

                    serverApater.chanColor(viewHolder[0],position);
                    holder.name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    viewHolder[0] =holder;
                }
            });


        }
    }


    private void initWeb(String s){

        if (isPlaying){
            player.release();

        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);

        webView.loadUrl(s);
        webView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        playerLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

    }

    public void iniMoviePlayer(String url,String type,Context context){

        Log.e("vTYpe :: ",type);

        if (type.equals("embed") || type.equals("vimeo") || type.equals("gdrive")){
            initWeb(url);
        }else {
            initVideoPlayer(url,context,type);
        }
    }

    public void initVideoPlayer(String url,Context context,String type){

        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        if (player!=null){
            player.release();

        }

        webView.setVisibility(GONE);
        playerLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);


        TrackSelector trackSelector = new
                DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        simpleExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                Log.e("Visibil", String.valueOf(visibility));
                if (visibility==0){
                    imgBack.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    imgFull.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    imgfit.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    imgBack.setVisibility(GONE);
                    imgFull.setVisibility(GONE);
                    imgfit.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);


        MediaSource mediaSource = null;

        if (type.equals("hls")){
            mediaSource = hlsMediaSource(uri,context);


        }else if (type.equals("youtube")){
            Log.e("youtube url  :: ",url);
            extractYoutubeUrl(url,context);
        }
        else if (type.equals("rtmp")){
            mediaSource=rtmpMediaSource(uri);
        }else {
            mediaSource=mediaSource(uri);
        }

        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);

        player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {




                if (playWhenReady && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {

                    isPlaying=true;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));

                }
                else if (playbackState==Player.STATE_READY){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isPlaying=false;
                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                }
                else if (playbackState==Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                    isPlaying=false;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                } else {
                    // player paused in any state
                    isPlaying=false;
                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                }

            }
        });


    }


    private void extractYoutubeUrl(String url,Context context) {


        new YouTubeExtractor(context) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {
                    int itag = 18;
                    String downloadUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
                    Log.e("YOUTUBE::", String.valueOf(downloadUrl));

                    try {

                        MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSource(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
                        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);


                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }


                }
            }
        }.extract(url, true, true);


    }


    private MediaSource rtmpMediaSource(Uri uri){

        MediaSource videoSource = null;

        RtmpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();
        videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);

        return  videoSource;

    }


    private MediaSource hlsMediaSource(Uri uri,Context context){

        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/JioTV/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"), bandwidthMeter);
        MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);

        return videoSource;

    }


    private MediaSource mediaSource(Uri uri){

        return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer")).
                createMediaSource(uri);

    }

    private void addToFav(String url){

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    if (response.getString("status").equals("success")){
                        new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconSuccess(response.getString("message"));
                        isFav=true;
                        imgAddFav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_favorite_24);
                    }else {
                        new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError(response.getString("message"));
                    }

                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError(getString(R.string.error_toast));
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


    }

    private void getTvData(String vtype,String vId){


        String type = "&&type="+vtype;
        String id = "&id="+vId;
        String url = new ApiResources().getDetails()+type+id;

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

                try {
                    tvName.setText(response.getString("tv_name"));
                    tvDes.setText(response.getString("description"));
                    V_URL=response.getString("stream_url");


                    CommonModels model=new CommonModels();
                    model.setTitle("HD");
                    model.setStremURL(V_URL);
                    model.setServerType(response.getString("stream_from"));
                    listDirector.add(model);



                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("all_tv_channel");
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        CommonModels models =new CommonModels();
                        models.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("poster_url"));
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("tv_name"));
                        models.setVideoType("tv");
                        models.setId(jsonObject.getString("live_tv_id"));
                        listRelated.add(models);

                    }
                    relatedTvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    JSONArray serverArray = response.getJSONArray("additional_media_source");
                    for (int i = 0;i<serverArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=serverArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("label"));
                        models.setStremURL(jsonObject.getString("url"));
                        models.setServerType(jsonObject.getString("source"));


                        listDirector.add(models);
                    }
                    serverApater.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private void getSeriesData(String vtype,String vId){

        String type = "&&type="+vtype;
        String id = "&id="+vId;
        String url = new ApiResources().getDetails()+type+id;

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                try {
                    tvName.setText(response.getString("title"));
                    tvRelease.setText("Release On "+response.getString("release"));
                    tvDes.setText(response.getString("description"));

                    //----realted post---------------
                    JSONArray relatedArray = response.getJSONArray("related_tvseries");
                    for (int i = 0;i<relatedArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=relatedArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        models.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail_url"));
                        models.setId(jsonObject.getString("videos_id"));
                        models.setVideoType("tvseries");

                        listRelated.add(models);
                    }
                    relatedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //----episode------------
                    JSONArray mainArray = response.getJSONArray("season");


                    for (int i = 0;i<mainArray.length();i++){
                        //epList.clear();

                        JSONObject jsonObject=mainArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        String season_name=jsonObject.getString("seasons_name");
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("seasons_name"));


                        Log.e("Season Name 1::",jsonObject.getString("seasons_name"));

                        JSONArray episodeArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("episodes");
                        List<EpiModel> epList=new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int j=0;j<episodeArray.length();j++){

                            JSONObject object =episodeArray.getJSONObject(j);

                            EpiModel model=new EpiModel();
                            model.setSeson(season_name);
                            model.setEpi(object.getString("episodes_name"));
                            model.setStreamURL(object.getString("file_url"));
                            model.setServerType(object.getString("file_type"));
                            epList.add(model);
                        }
                        models.setListEpi(epList);
                        listDirector.add(models);

                        episodeAdapter=new EpisodeAdapter(DetailsActivity.this,listDirector);
                        rvServer.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
                        episodeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


    }


    private void getData(String vtype,String vId){


        String type = "&&type="+vtype;
        String id = "&id="+vId;


        String url = new ApiResources().getDetails()+type+id;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                try {
                    tvName.setText(response.getString("title"));
                    tvRelease.setText("Released On "+response.getString("release"));
                    tvDes.setText(response.getString("description"));

                    //----realted post---------------
                    JSONArray relatedArray = response.getJSONArray("related_movie");
                    for (int i = 0;i<relatedArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=relatedArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        models.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail_url"));
                        models.setId(jsonObject.getString("videos_id"));
                        models.setVideoType("movie");

                        listRelated.add(models);
                    }
                    relatedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added adapter.setOnItemClickListener in your activity?

Comment: Have you added adapter.setOnItemClickListener in your activity?

Comment: change first line of activity public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener

Comment: @DharmenderManral doing so throws this error "Class 'DetailsActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'" Please read my other response in your written answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
// i have edit your adapter class

public class ServerApater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder> {

private List<CommonModels> items = new ArrayList<>();
private Context ctx;
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;


public ServerApater(Context context, List<CommonModels> items,View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    this.items = items;
    ctx = context;
    this.onClickListener=onClickListener;
}


@Override
public ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder vh;
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_server, parent, false);
    v.findViewById(R.id.card_view_home).setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    vh = new ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    CommonModels obj = items.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(obj.getTitle());



    if (position==0){
        viewHolder=holder;
        new DetailsActivity().iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),ctx);
        holder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    holder.cardView.setTag(obj);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public CardView cardView;

    public OriginalViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        cardView=v.findViewById(R.id.card_view_home);
    }
}

public void chanColor(ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder,int pos){

    if (pos!=0){
        viewHolder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_60));
    }

    if (holder!=null){
        holder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_60));
    }
 }

}


// call Adapter from activity like this
 ServerApater serverApater=new ServerApater(this,"pass here commonModel type 
 list",this);


// implement View.OnClickListener with Activity like this
 AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener


// then implement onclick() method
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.card_view_home:
            CommonModels obj = (CommonModels) v.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(obj.getStremURL()), "video/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193910/discussion-on-answer-by-dharmender-manral-getting-link-from-adapter-to-activity).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your adapter with this

```
public class ServerApater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder> {

    private List<CommonModels> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context ctx;

    private ServerApater.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    private ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder viewHolder;



    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ServerApater.OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }



    public ServerApater(Context context, List<CommonModels> items) {
        this.items = items;
        ctx = context;
    }


    @Override
    public ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder vh;
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_server, parent, false);
        vh = new ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        CommonModels obj = items.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(obj.getTitle());



        if (position==0){
            viewHolder=holder;
            new DetailsActivity().iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),ctx);
            holder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, items.get(position));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name;
        public CardView cardView;

        public OriginalViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            cardView=v.findViewById(R.id.card_view_home);
        }
    }

    public void chanColor(ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder,int pos){

        if (pos!=0){
            viewHolder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_60));
        }

        if (holder!=null){
            holder.name.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_60));
        }



    }

}
```

And add this code to your activity:

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

//Then implement the listener

@Override
onItemClick(int position, CommonModels obj){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(obj.getStremURL()), "video/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
}
```

Comment: imgBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            onItemClick(int position, CommonModels obj){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(obj.getStremURL()), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));

            }
        });

Comment: Says Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnClickListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'